# Is there a way to select an element from a dictionary using a non-existent member variable?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I have a class `Example` which contains a dictionary object `Dict` and as such I can access a dictionary value with key `"X"` using `Example.Dict["X"]`.

However, I'm wondering if it's possible to carry out these accesses as follows: `Example.X`.

I would usually handle this using a basic compiler macro in C or C++ but seeing as C# doesn't have this feature I'm wondering if it is possible via reflection or otherwise.

Comment: You can do this with `dynamic` and `ExpandoObject`, but it's not something I'd recommend over `Example["X"]` or `Example.Dict["X"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `DynamicObject`:

```
public class Example : DynamicObject
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Dict { get; } = new Dictionary<string, string>() { ["Foo"] = "bar" };

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        result = null;
        if (!Dict.TryGetValue(binder.Name, out var value))
            return false;
        result = value;
        return true;
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        if (Dict.ContainsKey(binder.Name))
        {
            Dict[binder.Name] = value?.ToString();
            return true;
        }
        return Dict.TryAdd(binder.Name, value?.ToString());
    }
}
```

An an example above I have initialised the `Dictionary<string,string>` with a default element. This allows me to write code such as:

```
dynamic ex = new Example();
Console.WriteLine(ex.Foo); // Outputs "bar"

ex.SomethingElse = "SomeValue"; // sets an element in the dictionary
```

Whether this is a *good idea* is an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Do you can do it with `ExpandoObject`, without the boilerplate.